# Javascript object notation

Tags: javascript

I did some manipulations and stored the values in arrays say, miles and type. Now I need to display it as an object with their own specific properties. 
Now I have

```
obj ={ 
    "miles" : [500,200], 
    "type": ["fer","bug"] 
};
```

I need to return object in the format

```
obj = { 
    "fer" : 500 , 
    "bug" : 200 
};
```

Thanks.
Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Use a loop on the arrays and assign properties to the new object?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think that is what he needs var i = 0; for(var key in obj.type){  var val = obj.miles[i]; newObj[key] = val; i++; }

Answer (score 3):

Iterate and create a new object

```js
var obj = { "miles" : [500,200], "type": ["fer","bug"] };
    
var obj2 = {};
    
for (var i=0; i<obj.type.length; i++) {
    obj2[obj.type[i]] = obj.miles[i];
}

// for snippet output
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj2, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var out = {};
for (var i = 0; i < obj.type.length; i++) {
    out[obj.type[i]] = obj.miles[i] || 0; // Just to be safe :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both type and miles have same length, you can do something like this.

```
obj ={ "miles" : [500,200], "type": ["fer","bug"] };
var length = obj.type.length;
var finalObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    finalObj[obj.type[i]] = obj.miles[i]
}
```

`finalObj` will be updated output.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lo-dash's `zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject):

> Creates an object composed from arrays of keys and values. Provide either a single two dimensional array, i.e. [[key1, value1], [key2, value2]] or two arrays, one of keys and one of corresponding values.

The `.type` property is the array of keys mapping to the values in the `.miles` property.

The code would be a single line:

```
var convertedObj = _.zipObject(obj.type, obj.miles);
```